# Create my own navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift

I have a parent viewController say `mainVC`.
On the bottom it has a tools bar subView - `UIView`,  with buttons.

When I press these buttons, I would like to push/transition between 3 controllers, but I would like to **keep this bottom tool bar on mainVC on top all the time**.

If I simply push a new controller it will cover my mainVC - hence the tool bar.

How can I get this effect **programmatically** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do is embed a new view controller. Basically you attach an instance of a view controller to another view controller through some view...

You need to call `addChildViewController` on parent and when transitioning there are `willMove` and `didMove` which will trigger appropriate events on your new view controller. Otherwise you need to add the view of the view controller to the target view as a subview.

Check the following which is a stripped version of what I am using:

```
class ContentControllerView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var parentViewController: UIViewController?
    private(set) var currentController: UIViewController?

    private var addedConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

    func setViewController(controller: UIViewController?) {
        guard let parentViewController = parentViewController else {
            print("ContentControllerView error: You need to set a parentViewController to add a new view controller")
            return
        }

        if controller?.view != currentController?.view {

            currentController?.willMove(toParentViewController: nil) // Notify the current controller it will move off the parent
            controller?.willMove(toParentViewController: parentViewController) // Notify the new controller it will move to the parent
            if let controller = controller {
                parentViewController.addChildViewController(controller) // Add child controller
            }
            let toRemove = addedConstraints
            addedConstraints.removeAll()

            controller?.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // Disable this to add custom constraints
            if let controller = controller {
                self.addSubview(controller.view) // Add as subview

                addedConstraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: controller.view, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
                addedConstraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: controller.view, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
                addedConstraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: controller.view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
                addedConstraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: controller.view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))

                // Assign new constraints
                self.addConstraints(addedConstraints)
            }
            controller?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.layoutIfNeeded()

            toRemove.forEach { self.removeConstraint($0) }
            self.currentController?.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true

            controller?.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)


            self.currentController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
            self.currentController?.didMove(toParentViewController: nil) // Notify the current controller it did move off the parent
            self.currentController?.removeFromParentViewController() // remove the current controller from parrent
            controller?.didMove(toParentViewController: parentViewController) // Notify the new controller it did move to the parent

            self.currentController = controller
            self.superview?.setNeedsLayout()
            (self.superview ?? self).layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    func clear() {
        guard currentController != nil else {
            return
        }

        setViewController(controller: nil)
    }

}
```

You can use this view in code or in Storyboard. Note that `parentViewController` MUST be set. So in storyboard you would add a normal `UIView` above your bar and then set its class to `ContentControllerView`. Then you ctrl+drag from it to its view controller and select `parentViewController`.

Then in the code you can call `setViewController` on it with desired view controller. In your case that is your navigation controller which will then work internally.

The stripped part is I removed everything related to animations. Consequently I am pretty sure there are some extra calls to layout in there left.

Comment: This is the same solution as the one from @Sweeper but is using a custom solution for "container view". The reason for this is that provided container view was designed as stupid as it gets, this object is completely unmaintainable. Still a container view should be enough to achieve this task.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to use one view controller with the toolbar as the only subview. You can call this `MyToolBarController`. Then, add a container view into `MyToolBarController`.

[image]

Container views are controlled by other view controllers, so you can make one of your 3 VCs to control it. When you present a new VC, it should still be presented in the container view. Since this all happens in `MyToolBarController`, the toolbar will still be there.

Comment: Thanks, so whats really is container view ? in this case it could just be a scrollView that I load 3 controllers into . My problem with that, is that viewControllers that been loaded into another view that is smaller then screen size (minus the toolbar), will still have the view.frame.height property as a full screen size, and the content will not be adapted to the container- that is to say - to get view.frame.height = screenHeight-toolBarHeight

Comment: @Curnelious I am referring to the container view you can add in the storyboard.

Comment: I would like to do everything with code. If I load a controller to a container view, this controller will get the height of the container ? (screen height minus toolbar height) ?

Comment: @Curnelious In fact, controllers don't have heights. The views they control have heights. So, yes, you will get the container view's height.

Comment: yea I meant controller.view height. When I load them into a scrollview, their view's height still reads as a full screen height even that the scroller's height is smaller then screen's height.

Comment: @Curnelious Don't put the view into a scroll view and don't use a scroll view at all. Make the view controller control a `UIView` which acts as a container.

Comment: Ok thanks I am trying now and will accept it if it works.

Comment: I am having hard time to figure how to do this only with code. No single simple example on the internet, how to load a container and load controllers into it. Many unclear information about constrains and things like that. I am not sure why this subject is so vague.

Comment: Does a container view is just a UIView ? I just can't understand this subject. Can you show example that do NOT include any story board setup ?